# Getting attribute values of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to get attribute values of the multiple elements in a selection as an array, but I cannot find a concise way.

For example, in a `svg` element, there are some `circle`s and you need to get `cx` attribute of the all of them.

I tried:

```
var cxs = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx");
```

But the result is only a value (say "523.4777243042896") of one circle, and I need all `cx`s.
The coordinates of the circles are calculated with a complicated simulation algorithm, so it is impossible to get them using the original data.
Is there any good way to get all values?

Thanks.

Comment: If you bind this to the data (the array you mentioned), say `d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle").data(array)`, then you can simply use `.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})`, assuming the data array has the X coords as a key-value pair like x: someValue. Without seeing any code, this would be my guesstimate.

Comment: Yes, actually this solution works in my case because I'm using d3.layout.force, which binds x and y attributes to the corresponding datum. But in general, this does not work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to get a list of the `cx` values. So, here's one way you could do that.

```
var cxs = [];
d3.selectAll("circle")[0].forEach(function(circle) {
  cxs.push(circle.getAttribute('cx'));
});
```

To make it a little shorter you could use `map()`

```
var cxs = d3.selectAll("circle")[0].map(function(circle) {
  return circle.getAttribute('cx');
});
```

Comment: This solution seems to be a realistic workaround now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**d3 v7 answer**

The [nodes()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#control-flow) function returns an array of the underlaying element.

```
const cxs = d3.selectAll("circle").nodes().map(circle => 
  circle.getAttribute('cx');
});
```