# Cannot get d3 selection's updated data when key is used

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a visualization of sorting algorithms with *d3.js*. To this end, I'd like to create several circles with different radii and then swap them one by one as sorting algorithm work. Trying to do this, I encountered the following problem: when I update the data associated with d3 selection and then try to get it back using `.data()`, I get unchanged data (as I didn't update it). This problem occur only if I use `key` function to track objects.

The code follows. If you click "check", you get `[1, 3, 2]` in console, which is the correct initial state. If then you click "do", `update` function will be invoked and circles will change their positions according to new data. However, if you click then "check" again, you still get `[1, 3, 2]` and not `[3, 2, 1]` as expected.

So, there are two questions:

1. Why does it behave in such way?
2. How to overcome this, i.e. to get the updated data from the selection?

```js
  
    function key(d) {
        return d
      }
    
    function update(data) { 
      return d3.select("#picture")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data, key)
        .transition()
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return (i+1)*50;});
    }
    
    $(function() {
      d3.select("#picture")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data([1, 3, 2], key)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return (i+1)*50;})
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", function(d) {return (d+1)*10;})
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue");
      
      $("#do_it").click(function() {
         update([3, 2, 1]);   
      });
      $("#check").click(function() {
         console.log(d3.select("#picture")
                  .selectAll("circle").data());
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <button id="check">check</button>
   <button id="do_it">do</button><br/>
   <svg id="picture" width=300 height=150></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the data won't change **precisely** because you used a key. If you hadn't used a key, the order would change.

The circles are created with this relationship:

- circle `0` has `1` as datum
- circle `1` has `3` as datum
- circle `2` has `2` as datum.

Each datum is used as a key, to identify the circle. When you update the data, this relationship won't change, again, because you have set the key.

When you console.log the data after the update ("do it") function, you're not getting the data regarding the new *positions* of the circles. When you console.log the data after the update, in fact, you're getting the same thing:

- circle `0` has `1` as datum
- circle `1` has `3` as datum
- circle `2` has `2` as datum.

These are not the *positions* of the circles, but the order they were created.

However, you can see that the *position* is changing if you put a console.log inside your `update` function:

```
console.log("circle at position " + i + ", data: " + d)
```

Check the demo, click "do" and see the data associated with the circles at different *positions*:

```js
function key(d) {
        return d
      }
    
    function update(data) { 
      return d3.select("#picture")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data, key)
        .transition()
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        console.log("circle at position " + i + ", data: " + d)   
        return (i+1)*50;});
    }
    
    $(function() {
      d3.select("#picture")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data([1, 3, 2], key)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return (i+1)*50;})
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", function(d) {return (d+1)*10;})
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue");
      
      $("#do_it").click(function() {
         update([3, 2, 1]);   
      });
      $("#check").click(function() {
         console.log(d3.select("#picture")
                  .selectAll("circle").data());
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <button id="check">check</button>
   <button id="do_it">do</button><br/>
   <svg id="picture" width=300 height=150></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Is it true that there's no simple way to retrieve positions of elements using something like `.data()` method in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the positions. Check this fiddle, the `console` shows the x position of the big circle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/fget7ouu/

Comment: Good! I actually want to get an array like `[3, 2, 1]` after I press 'do' and 'check'. I can try to reconstruct it from `cx`'s or store position in tag along with `cx`, but not sure yet how to get an array of the values.

Comment: Tried `d3.select("#picture").selectAll("circle").attr("cx")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally found how to do it, but not sure it's the best way, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42423169/3025981).

Answer (score 1):

Gerardo Furtado's answer explains the reasons of such behaviour, and here is an answer to the second part of my question: how to overcome this.

I'm storing actual position of element in its `data-position` attribute and then restore original data from that positional information.

I'm not sure that this is a most elegant solution, so comments and alternatives are much appreciated.

```js
function key(d) {
  return d
}

function update(data) {
  return d3.select("#picture")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data, key)
    .transition()
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return (i + 1) * 50;
    })
    .attr("data-position", function(d, i) {
      return i;
    });
}

function get_data(initial_array) {
  // BASED ON: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22118052/3025981
  var indexes = []
  d3.select("#picture")
    .selectAll("circle").each(function(d, i) {
      indexes.push(+d3.select(this).attr('data-position'))
    });
  // END BASED
  var data = []
  for (i = 0; i < initial_array.length; i++) {
    data[indexes[i]] = initial_array[i];
  }
  return data;
}

$(function() {
  initial_array = [1, 3, 2]
  d3.select("#picture")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(initial_array, key)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return (i + 1) * 50;
    })
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return (d + 1) * 10;
    })
    .attr("data-position", function(d, i) {
      return i;
    })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue");

  $("#do_it").click(function() {
    update([3, 2, 1]);
  });
  $("#check").click(function() {
    console.log(get_data(initial_array));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="check">check</button>
<button id="do_it">do</button>
<br/>
<svg id="picture" widht=300 height=300></svg>
```